# How do I successfully append a string to a url in a bookmarklet without it repeating?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, window.location

I have the following javascript code which I am using as a bookmarklet. It works well, but it appears I am appending the string 'e?nooverride=1' numerous times. I only want to replace the string once.

Here is the url: https://c.cs24.visual.force.com/apex/page1?id=0061A00001386pX
Here is the desired url: https://c.cs24.visual.force.com/apex/page1?id=0061A00001386pX

Here is my code:

```
var urlString = window.location.href;
if(urlString.includes("apex/page1?id=")){
    urlString = urlString.replace("apex/page1?id=", "");
}

else if(urlString.includes("apex/page2?id=")){
    urlString = urlString.replace("apex/page2?id=", "");
}

if(urlString.includes("&sfdc.override=1")){
    urlString = urlString.replace("&sfdc.override=1", "");
}

window.location.href=urlString+'/e?nooverride=1';
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. I was apparently using the back/forward browser button and that was messing up with what was stored in the url.

Comment: You should close/delete the question.